# Open Url in c# windows application

Tags: c#, url

I need to open an web page in my windows application i done it.
help of this code

```
ProcessStartInfo sInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("http://24.10.0.123/license.php");
Process.Start(sInfo);
```

it opens an url page .

here it gives me an message like true r false like this

[image]

it gives false message .

if its false i need to get my form1 page

if it gives true i need to get my form2 page

i realy get confused how to make code for this. sorry if my english poor . help me

Comment: look up using the httpclient class

Comment: It sounds like you really shouldn't be involving a web browser in this at all.  Use something like the `HttpClient` object to make an HTTP request to the URL and examine the response in code.

Comment: i got it @ BugFinder & @David thank u. [link](http://www.dotnetperls.com/httpclient) this helps me

Answer (score -1):

Below is a sample working asynchronously.

There are so many other manners to achieve on, but I did it the fastest to help you.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var task = LoadUrl(new Uri("http://www.google.com"));

        task.Wait();

        Console.WriteLine(Encoding.Default.GetString(task.Result));

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static async Task<byte[]> LoadUrl(Uri uri)
    {
        using (var webclient = new WebClient())
        {
            using (var stream = webclient.OpenRead(uri))
            {
                return await Task.Run(new Func<byte[]>(() => { return webclient.DownloadData(uri); }));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use `webclient.DownloadDataAsync()`.